# neo4j apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll() performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 130 million nodes with label `Snp`. I want to convert the property `position` from `string` to `int` for all nodes. I'm using neo4j 3.0.4 with apoc version 3.0.4.1.

Due to the large number of nodes this has to be done in batches. I tried the `apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll()` procedure for this

```
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
    'MATCH (n:Snp) WITH n RETURN id(n) AS id_n', 
    'MATCH (n:Snp) where id(n)={id_n} SET n.position = toInt(n.position)',
    20000
)
```

I thought this matches all nodes in batches and then calls the second query for each batch. But it blocks neo4j with frequent GC and growing memory usage. The procedure has not finished in 3 hours.

It works if the first `MATCH` is limited, the following takes ~20 seconds:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
    'MATCH (n:Snp) WITH n LIMIT 1000000 RETURN id(n) AS id_n', 
    'MATCH (n:Snp) where id(n)={id_n} SET n.position = toInt(n.position)',
    20000
)
```

However, this is not the point of the procedure I think. Can I somehow use it differently to convert a property for a large set of nodes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first Cypher statement you pass to the `apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll` procedure will attempt to get all 130 million `Snp` nodes. This is probably why you are seeing high memory usage and slow processing. Batch processing is only performed on the second Cypher statement.

The `apoc.periodic.commit` procedure should work better for your use case. The following call will get and convert 100K nodes at a time until they have all been processed.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
  'MATCH (n:Snp) WHERE TOINT(n.position) <> n.position WITH n LIMIT {limit} SET n.position = TOINT(n.position) RETURN COUNT(*);',
  {limit: 100000}
)
```

The `apoc.periodic.commit` procedure repeatedly invokes its Cypher query until it returns 0. The `MATCH` clause filters out nodes that already have an integer `position`. The `limit` parameter specifies the batch size.

Comment: The `toInt() <> str` part is great! I used `.commit()` with a query that sets a label on visited nodes before I could read your answer. It worked but now I have to get rid of the label.

Comment: @cybersam, that is a beautiful answer, Michael. Simple but perfect.

Comment: Thanks, but who is "Michael"?

Comment: How does it work in case of parameters being passed? Are parameters also read in batches?

Comment: Parameters (e.g., lists) are not automatically batched. But you might be able to do something clever with lists in the Cypher. You can create a new question if you have a concrete problem.